# ruby 1.8 undefined method `instance_variable_defined?'

Tags: ruby

I have been working on my Ruby. When trying to execute this simple example from the [Ruby Object documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001030), I get this error:

> undefined method `instance_variable_defined?'

This is my code:

```
class Fred
  def initialize(p1, p2)
    @a, @b = p1, p2
  end
end

fred = Fred.new('cat', 99)
fred.instance_variable_defined?(:@a)    #=> true
fred.instance_variable_defined?("@b")   #=> true
fred.instance_variable_defined?("@c")   #=> false
```

What have I done wrong? I tested this on another machine with Ubuntu 10.04 and it works fine. I'm using Centos 5.5 by the way.

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Tell your installed Ruby version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that you're using an ancient version of Ruby (1.8.5 or earlier), as `Object#instance_variable_defined?` has been in Ruby since 1.8.6.

Comment: Thanks for your response guys, dmarkow was right I am using ruby 1.8.5 will attemp to upgrade to 1.8.6 so I can start using DataMapper library.

Comment: If you're going to upgrade, you might as well use the most current of the 1.8 branch (1.8.7). http://rvm.beginrescueend.com is probably your best best to get this installed.